# Handsontable - Table not rendered

Tags: php, handsontable

I am trying to load data in handsontable.

The HTML file is very basic:
just a table and a button to load data sent by a php script (named *actions.php*):

```
<!doctype html>

<html>

<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="dist/handsontable.full.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="dist/handsontable.full.css">
</head>

<body>

<div id="hot"></div>
<br />
<input id="try" type="button" value="Try" />

</body>

<script>
$(function() {
    var objectData = [
        {id: 1, name: 'Ted Right', address: ''},
        {id: 2, name: 'Frank Honest', address: ''}];

    $('#hot').handsontable({
        data: objectData,
        colHeaders: true,
        minSpareRows: 1
    });

    var hot = $("#hot").handsontable('getInstance');

    $("#try").click(function(){
        $.getJSON("actions2.php", function(result){
            console.log (objectData);
            console.log (JSON.parse(result));
            hot.render();
        });
    }); 

});
</script>

</html>
```

The php is also very basic

```
<?php
$result=array(
    array("id" => 5, "name" => "Bill Gates", "address"=>"zzz"),
    array("id" => 6, "name" => "Steve Jobs", "address"=>"xxx")
);

echo json_encode(json_encode($result));
?>
```

When I click on the "Try" button, the *objectData* is well updated, but not the table despite the *hot.render()* instruction.

Any idea about what I am doing wrong ?

Rgds

Answer (score 1):

I found the issues.

*.loadData* method was missing in the js script and there is a *json_encode* error in the php

Here is a working example.

```
<html>

<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="dist/handsontable.full.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="dist/handsontable.full.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div id="hot" />
    <br />
    <input id="go" type="button" value="Click me" />
</body>

<script>
$(function() {
    var objectData = [
        {id: 1, name: 'Ted Right', address: ''},
        {id: 2, name: 'Frank Honest', address: ''}];

    $('#hot').handsontable({
        data: objectData,
        colHeaders: true
    });

    var hot = $("#hot").handsontable('getInstance');

    $("#go").click(function(){

        $.getJSON("actions2.php", function(result){
            hot.loadData(result);
            hot.render();
        });
    }); 

});
</script>

</html>
```

and the actions2.php file

```
<?php
$result=array(
    array("id" => 5, "name" => "Bill Gates", "address"=>"zzz","ee"=>"zz"),
    array("id" => 6, "name" => "Steve Jobs", "address"=>"xxx")
);

echo (json_encode($result));
?>
```